# Restructure list of maps to one map in terraform

Tags: terraform

In my terraform code I'd like to merge the following list of maps to one map of maps.
The initial list of map looks as follows. Is there a way to do this? If there is not, is it possible to use the original list of maps in a for_each somehow? It only accepts set of strings or maps as far as I know. I tried restructuring it, but no luck.

```
[  
  {
    "repo1" = {
      "description" = "repo1 for something"
      "enforce_branch_policies" = true
      "name" = "repo1"
    }
  }
  {
    "repo2" = {
      "description" = "repo2 for something"
      "enforce_branch_policies" = true
      "name" = "repo2"
    }
  }
]
```

Expected map:

```
{
  "repo1" = {
    "description" = "repo1 for something"
    "enforce_branch_policies" = true
    "name" = "repo1"
   }
  "repo2" = {
     "description" = "repo2 for something"
     "enforce_branch_policies" = true
     "name" = "repo2"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can expand the list with [the `...` symbol](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments) directly to the `merge()` function.

```
repo_map = merge(local.repo_list...)
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes a missing `,` in the question between the two maps; otherwise it is a syntax error.

If you want to use this structure in a `for_each` meta-argument, then you can note that it is of type `list(map(object)))`. We can then use a `for` expression to reconstruct into a `map(object)` suitable for iteration:

```
# assumes value is stored in local.repos; modify for your personal config code accordingly
# repo stores the `map(object)` for each element in the list
# the keys and values functions return the keys and values as lists respectively
# the [0] syntax accesses the key and value for each repo map
for_each = { for repo in local.repos : keys(repo)[0] => values(repo)[0] }
```

This produces the expected value:

```
{
  repo1 = {
    description             = "repo1 for something"
    enforce_branch_policies = true
    name                    = "repo1"
  }
  repo2 = {
    description             = "repo2 for something"
    enforce_branch_policies = true
    name                    = "repo2"
  }
}
```

While you could also convert the type here from `list` to `set` with the `toset()` function, the return would not be a feasible structure for the `for_each` argument value.