# Terraform : merge list of maps and form one map including duplicate keys

Tags: terraform

I have a variables like this:

```
variable "domain" {
  default = ["dom1", "dom2"]
}

variable "feedback" {
  default = ["one", "two"]
}
```

Required output is

```
{
  "dom1" = "one"
  "dom2" = "one"
  "dom1" = "two"
  "dom2" = "two"
}
```

I tried the below one so far, by referring to this post - [Restructure list of maps to one map in terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70775328/restructure-list-of-maps-to-one-map-in-terraform)

```
merge(flatten([for domain in var.domain: [for feed in var.feedback: {"${domain}" = feed}]])...)
```

But the above removes duplicate keys, as below

```
{
  "dom1" = "two"
  "dom2" = "two"
}
```

is there any way to preserve duplicate keys? Or any other way to do it? Eventually i'm trying to pass that output to for_each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any way to preserve duplicate keys?

No, its not possible. Keys in map must be unique. But you can create **composite key**:

```
locals {
  one_map = merge([
    for domain in var.domain: {
      for feedback in var.feedback: 
        "${domain}-${feedback}" => {
          "domain" = domain
          "feedback" = feedback
        }
    }
  ]...)
}
```

which results in

```
{
  "dom1-one" = {
    "domain" = "dom1"
    "feedback" = "one"
  }
  "dom1-two" = {
    "domain" = "dom1"
    "feedback" = "two"
  }
  "dom2-one" = {
    "domain" = "dom2"
    "feedback" = "one"
  }
  "dom2-two" = {
    "domain" = "dom2"
    "feedback" = "two"
  }
}
```